# Running Mac OS X in non-apple hardware

Tags: macos, mac

I want to know if its "legal" to run Mac OS X in non apple hardware.

If not, what is the point of having to run Mac OS X in a apple hardware, when apple hardware is running Mac OS X already.

Comment: “If not, what is the point of having to run Mac OS X in a apple hardware, when apple hardware is running Mac OS X already.” — Because you pay for the hardware. The Mavericks upgrade is free. Also, OS X depends very heavily on the hardware involved, architecture, etc. I'd imagine that supporting and debugging OS X on other hardware would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is against the terms of [the EULA](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosx106.pdf):

> 2. Permitted License Uses and Restrictions.
>   A. Single Use License . Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, unless you have purchased a Family Pack or Upgrade license
>   for the Apple Software, you are granted a limited non-exclusive
>   license to install, use and run one **(1) copy of the Apple Software on
>   a single Apple-branded computer at a time**. You agree **not to install,
>   use or run the Apple Software on any non-Apple-branded computer**, or to
>   enable others to do so.

However, Apple has historically [not prosecuted individuals](http://www.applematters.com/article/why-does-apple-allow-personal-hackintoshes/) who violate this for hobby purposes, and have only gone after people who sell preinstalled systems (such as Psystar) or published how-to guides that involve downloading pirated/pre-modified versions.  And, of course you get absolutely no customer support or guarantee that it will continue to work.