# Has anyone been sued for using Mac OS on non-Apple hardware?

Tags: macos, license

I have read: https://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1011.pdf and [Is it possible to run macOS in a virtual machine on Linux?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274313/is-it-possible-to-run-macos-in-a-virtual-machine-on-linux) and [Running Mac OS X in non-apple hardware](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132122/running-mac-os-x-in-non-apple-hardware) and [Is installing Mavericks on Hackintosh legal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107324/is-installing-mavericks-on-hackintosh-legal) and [What are the licensing concerns running Mac OS X guest OS on VMWare ESXi 5.5 with non-apple hardware?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129161/what-are-the-licensing-concerns-running-mac-os-x-guest-os-on-vmware-esxi-5-5-wit)

My interpretation is that Apple only wants the user to run Mac OS on hardware they have made.

It seems questionable whether such a restriction would hold up in court - especially in EU.

None of the above answers whether it has been tested in court.

Has there ever been a case where Apple has sued a user, who has Apple hardware, that he does not use, but he instead runs Mac OS on non-Apple hardware? (e.g. a developer that tests software using Mac OS on Virtualbox on non-Apple hardware, but who owns Apple hardware that sits in a box in the attic).

Please note: I do not care about your opinion whether you think anything is legal/moral or not, or how you interpret the law in your country. You can post those opinions and advice on https://law.stackexchange.com. I am interested in facts.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111988/discussion-on-question-by-ole-tange-has-anyone-been-sued-for-using-mac-os-on-non).

Comment: I’m going to put a hold on comments. Please engage in chat or on [meta]. This seems pretty clearly out of bounds for this site scope so let’s not beat up the question solely because it’s not on-topic with more down votes.

Answer (score 1):

There was a company that tried to manufacture their own computers, with MacOS installed on them.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psystar_Corporation

Apple sued them out of existence.

The legal validity of End-User-Licence-Agreements has been confirmed in several cases in many jurisdictions. (Despite earlier rulings on software as goods, e.g. the first sale doctrine.)

Here's an article about a ruling that EULAs are binding in the US:

https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2010/09/the-end-of-used-major-ruling-upholds-tough-software-licenses/

However, it's unlikely that Apple would come down hard on individuals who are privately breaking the EULA, with no profit motive.

Comment: It is unclear to me how Psystar think they obtained a license for MacOS. Did they ship their system including an original Mac that the user would then not use? If not then this seems rather different from the situation I am interested in.

Comment: As said, if you want to look at the case law that has confirmed the validity of EULAs, then there is plenty of it, and you can look it up. Breaking the EULA is a de jure breach of contract. Of course, it would be a PR disaster for Apple to sue some 14-yar-old Hackintosh fan. 
What more 'interest' are you after?

Comment: I don't think Psystar  ever thought they had a valid license. I've always thought they went in to prove EULAs are ignorable & learned to their cost that for a company, they're not.

Comment: If not having a valid licence and ignoring the EULA is punishable, then having a valid licence, agreeing to it, and then breaking it is also a violation, arguably greater. PsyStar had one licence for the MacMini they used to copy from.

Comment: *de jure* means *rightful* as in "He's the de jure heir to the thone."  What's a rightful breach of contract, @benwiggy?  Do you mean *de facto*?

Comment: @Allan, No: 'de jure' means 'in law' (in opposition to de facto, which is what actually happens in the world regardless of the law.) Breaking the EULA is a clear breach of law, but in the real world is unlikely to bring consequences.

Comment: You're using it wrong is my point.  You can't "as a matter of law of lawfulness breach a contract." You can have a de jure organization like a de jure governmental agency.  But a breach of contract doesn't necessarily break a law.  There is no law that says you must install  macOS on Apple hardware.

Comment: Breaking the EULA is a breach of contract "in law". That's what I meant, and that's what my comment says. I'm not suggesting any of the things in your last comment.

Comment: *breach of contract "in law"*  that's not even a concept @benwiggy - Law can govern the agreement as to what's legal or not, and you can break a law that causes a breach, but there's no concept of breaching a contract "in law."  So, as I said, you're using the term incorrectly.